# FullCalendar jquery json Events MySQL Problem

Tags: mysql, json, events, fullcalendar

I've got the problem that i can't display events in my Calendar and i don't now why... the dateformat is correct... if i try it with normal events out of the json... i mean with the sample events out of the Demo... it works fine... but if get my events out of my MSQL i never see an event

heres the code from the SQl Satemaent and the Array Creation

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $start = $res['start'];
  $end = $res['end'];
  $title = $res['title'];
  $eventStart = ($start/1000);
  $eventEnd = ($end/1000);
  $rows[] = array(
        'id'        => $res['id'],
        'title'     => $title,
        'start'     => str_replace("+00:00", " +01:00",date('c',$eventStart)),
        'end'       => str_replace("+00:00", " +01:00",date('c',$eventEnd)),
        'allDay'    => false,
     );
}
return $rows;
```

and here are the json.php

```
$arrEvents = getView(($_REQUEST['start']*1000), ($_REQUEST['end'])*1000);
var_dump($arrEvents);
echo json_encode($arrEvents);
```

this is the result:

```
[{"id":"10","title":"Urlaub","start":"2010-11-24T07:30:00+01:00","end":"2010-11-24T16:15:00+01:00","allDay":false}]
```

so if anyone can give me a hand or a tip how i can fix this bug... i'm very pleasend

thanks

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors?  What does your JS look like?

Comment: $('#cal').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: "month",
  header:{
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'month'
  },
  editable: false,
  selectable: true,
  droppable: true,
  events: 'inc/json.php',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try the following sample code using your "start" value:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var today=new Date('2010-11-24T07:30:00+01:00');
alert(today);
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get "Invalid Date" for the alert.  Try formatting your dates for start and end via the [date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)'s valid formats.  FullCalendar uses JS date formatting under the hood.

Comment: so my date is now iso 8861 valid... but theres another little problem hoq i can send above the Request the full timestamp?

Comment: @Timberwolf - what do you mean?  Above the request?  As in as part of your header?

Comment: no the question was: above the Request :) but i've got something else... array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "testevent1"
    ["start"]=>
    string(25) "2010-11-24T08:30:00+01:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(25) "2010-11-24T22:00:00+01:00"
    ["allDay"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
[{"id":"10","title":"testevent1","start":"2010-11-24T08:30:00+01:00","end":"2010-11-24T22:00:00+01:00","allDay":false}]

Comment: what is wrong with this Array? i use to convert the date the php function date like this (date('c', $timestamp)).... and i found in the docu that this format is correct.... i don't understand that

Comment: @Timberwolf - try making a date out of that string in some test JS.  Make sure it works.  Find a format that works an duse it.

Answer (score 0):

set allDaySlot: false parameter when you initialize:

```
                    editable: true,
                    theme: true,
                    contentHeight:600,
                    minTime: 7,
                    maxTime: 18,
                    allDaySlot: false,
```